# Use es6 import in vuejs to import d3-sankey

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to use d3js with d3-sankey plugin in a vuejs application.
I'm using : "d3": "^5.9.7" &"d3-sankey": "^0.12.1"
This is the script in my .vue

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import PageHeader from '@/components/Header.vue'

import * as d3 from 'd3';
import 'd3-sankey';

export default {
  name: 'sankey',
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
            errors: []
        }
    },
   mounted() {
          axios
            .get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/q-m/d3.chart.sankey/master/example/data/product.json')
            .then(response =>{
               var sankey = d3.sankey();
               console.log(sankey);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            })
   }
}
</script>
```

How should I import the plugin correctly please?

Comment: What's does the console tell you about the import ? Are you getting errors ? It would be easier for everyone to understand if you provide the logs about your issue.

Comment: Hello, I don't have errors in the server console (I'm using vu cli3) and the web browser console.

Comment: If you just want to make sure that you're importing correctly, I'm pretty sure you're already on the good way. I've never used d3 with vue directly but I can tell you it's not that far from what I see in this article: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/d3-js-and-vue-js-7a6a721eb79f

Comment: Thanks for the link. 
console.log(d3); is working
but var sankey = d3.sankey(); console.log(sankey); is not and it does not throw an error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am importing it like this in an Angular 8 application:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { sankey as d3Sankey, sankeyLinkHorizontal as d3SsankeyLinkHorizontal } from 'd3-sankey';
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
const sankeyDiagram = d3Sankey()
  .nodeWidth(15)
  .nodePadding(10)
  .extent([[1, 5], [this.width - 1, this.height - 5]]);
```

And I use the sankeyLinkHorizontal this way:

```
link.append('path')
    .attr('d', d3SsankeyLinkHorizontal())
    .attr('stroke', (d: any) => {
      return (this.edgeColor === 'none') ? '#aaa'
       : this.edgeColor === 'path' ? `url(#${d.uid})`
       : this.edgeColor === 'input' ? this.color(d.source.name)
       : this.color(d.target.name);
    })
    .attr('stroke-width', (d: any) => Math.max(1, d.width));
```

Comment: Thanks, I can print sankeyDiagram in the console now. I ll try to have something to show up before accepting your answer to be sure it worked. Is your example suppose to show something ?

Comment: No, this example is just the part of the code that uses the imported modules.

Comment: I don't think it worked, I should be able to call all d3 functions on the sankey object right ? sankey.layout(x) is not working.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find that method in the source code (https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey/blob/master/src/sankey.js). Maybe you are looking at an old or different version? Because I did find it here http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/c9b90689c1438f57d649/sankey.js, but that is not the same source and it is not the code for d3-sankey package that you are importing. In my Sankey diagram, I am not using sankey.layout, actually, it is similar to this one https://observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram and it is not being used there.

Comment: Okay thanks for the inputs. I noticed that I have these warning now :
 warning  in ./src/components/Sankey.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
"export 'sankey' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'
 warning  in ./src/components/Sankey.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
"export 'sankeyLinkHorizontal' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'

Comment: How are you importing d3 and d3-sankey modules?

Comment: Like you did, I fixed one warning with the second part of your code. I just have one left now : 
 warning in ./src/components/Sankey.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& "export 'sankey' (imported as 'd3') was not found

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram  example. Can you confirm that sankey = ƒ(…) means that it's a function with no parameters ? I

Comment: I almost managed to reproduce the example in vuejs but I don't understand what edgeColor represent. Any chance you could explain please ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer your previous question. Just in case, = f(...) in Observable means that the cell returns a function.
As you can see in this Observable (https://observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram) edgeColor is the value of the selected dropdown option, try changing the dropdown and see what happens. The values can be 'input', 'output', 'path' and 'none'. If you want to keep it simple, replace all that attribute function with:
.attr('stroke', '#aaa') and you will see the links colored of grey.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is working now. The only one thing left is for me to manage to get gradient colors. I replaced .attr("id", d => (d.uid = DOM.uid("link")).id) with .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "line" + i}) but this line seems important to get gradient, but I don't have access to DOM. I also set the color that way for now : .attr("stroke", d => self.color(d.source.name)). Color is the same function as in obsevablehq.

Comment: I have the tags <linearGradiant with the 2 <stops inside in my "<g" elements so maybe it's something else.

Comment: In the Observable, the gradients are created inside the if (edgeColor === "path") { block, if you want to use it, set the edgeColor to path or simply remove the if condition and use the block inside it. but that is only the definition, now you must reference it like this:         .attr('stroke', (d: any) => { return 'url(#' + d.uid + ')'; })

Comment: Thanks I read about it after you mentioned that I have to reference it. 
I managed to get gradiant like this, in append("path") :
.attr("stroke", d => "url(#"+d.uid+")")
and in apprend("linearGradiant") :
              .attr("id", function(d,i){ 
                d.uid = "line" + i;
                return "line" + i
                })

Comment: Yea everything is working expect these line : .nodeAlign(d3[`sankey${align[0].toUpperCase()}${align.slice(1)}`])
but it does not break the content. I learned a lot about d3js & vue with your help, thanks.

Comment: That line specifies the content alignment, it depends on your needs, in order to make it work, you can import the modules like we did before, `import { sankey as d3Sankey, sankeyLinkHorizontal as d3SsankeyLinkHorizontal,
  sankeyLeft as d3SankeyLeft,
  sankeyRight as d3SankeyRight,
  sankeyCenter as d3SankeyCenter,
  sankeyJustify as d3SankeJustify
 } from 'd3-sankey';` and then replace that line with `.nodeAlign(d3SankeyRight)` or the desired alignment. The observable does it that way because it assign the nodeAlign function depending on the selected value from the drop down.